# How can I accelerate the caching in Spark (Pyspark)?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to cache a dataframe in Pyspark(2.4.4), and the memory caching is slow.

I benchmark the Pandas caching with Spark caching, by reading the same file(CSV). Specifically, Pandas was 3-4 times faster.

Thanks,
In advance

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing apples and oranges. Pandas is a single machine single core data analysis library whereas pyspark is distributed (cluster computing) data analysis engine. That means you will never outperform pandas reading a small file on a single machine with pyspark due to the overhead (distributed architecture, JVM...). That also means that pyspark will outperform pandas as soon as your file exceeds a certain size.

You as a developer has to choose the solution which best fits your requirements. When pandas is faster for your project and you don't expect a huge increase of data in the future, use pandas. Otherwise use pyspark or dask or...

Comment: thanks for your answer! But my question it was about Spark configuration, if there is a parameter that I can change in order to increase the performance of caching. The comparison with Pandas it was only to have a lower bound that I could not break in a single machine.